# How to completely overwrite processor cache?

Tags: c++, arrays, caching

How can I overwrite the processor cache by using a normal C++ array?
I have done the following so far, but I just get a StackoverflowException which is not placed in the cache:

```
static const int CLEAR_CACHE_ARRAY_SIZE = 1000000;

void overwriteProcessorCache()
{
    double clearCacheArray[CLEAR_CACHE_ARRAY_SIZE];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < CLEAR_CACHE_ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
        clearCacheArray[i] = randomDouble();

    cout << "Ready!" << endl;
    cin.get();
};

double randomDouble()
{
    double random = ((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX);
    return random;
};
```

Comment: You'll need a dynamic array (`std::vector<double> array(1000000);`) to avoid stack overflow. Whether writing to that will reliably overwrite the cache is another matter, depending on the processor and its cache invalidation policy.

Comment: Why do you think you need to "overwrite the processor cache"? I'm thinking you may not understand what the cache is. Overwriting it is a pretty useless thing to do... Tell us what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Your array size is too big. Assuming a size of 8 for double, your array is ~7.6 GB in size, which cannot fit on the stack.

Comment: @wolfPack88: "cannot" on a current PC.

Comment: I recommend you search the web for "data cache optimization c++".

Comment: @DarkFalcon The thing is, that I need to implement some sorting algorithms and load the test data into the cache. So if I run a test the sorted data stays in cahce. For another test I need to overwrite the cache. It's just for testing reasons and to be sure, that the cache data is useless.

Comment: @wolfPack88 It's not that big. Its about 7.6 MByte.

Comment: Just a minor comment: you are using a "c-style array" and "std::array" is what I would call a "normal c++ array"

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That's obviously implied with literally every fact on this website.

Comment: Assuming 8 bytes per `double` your array is about 8 million bytes, 8 MB. That fits on the stack no problem on a PC, as long as you tell the compiler/linker to use a sufficiently large stack. The problem is probably that you have relied on a default very small stack size.